# Print from SD and connect to serial host at the same time

Tags: marlin, electronics, repetier, serial-connection

I am wondering if it is possible to print with a 3D printer from an SD card and connect to a serial host at the same time. I want to use the Marlin `M118` serial print command to trigger custom functions running on a Raspberry Pi. The RPi would be connected to the printer over serial but would not be sending G-code. Is this possible?

My printer is the Monoprice Mini Delta. It runs a Marlin based firmware and I can install standard Marlin on it if necessary.

Comment: Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done, but you need to have the right order of operations. [Octoprint](https://octoprint.org/) relies on such a setup.

- Set up the serial connection **first**, as sending the connect signal from your terminal or Raspberry to Marlin triggers the printer to reboot.
- After having the connection established, start the printjob either via the control buttons or the remote console (for example: Octoprint or Repetier Server, running on your Raspberry)

Note that you have to make sure not to dis- and reconnect the raspberry during print, as that might trigger a reboot of the printer!